# Yii1 class not found

Tags: php, yii

I got a class named Item in my project. On my local server there's error

```
: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

In each place where I'm creating new object of this's class. When I'm changing class name, in place where I'm creating object, for example

```
$model = new Item1();
```

I'm receiving normal error, with file name

```
Include(Item1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

This project is also existing on VPS Server, and everything is okay there. Code is exactly the same, I just pulled it from repository. I'm using XAMPP with PHP 5.6.32 on my computer.

Comment: What's in `Item` class?

Comment: Do you `import` the class in the config?